# Get/Find URL string component IF a string component exists

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parsing, url

Hello and thanks ahead for your help.
Looking to use JS/JQ to get a component of a URL on DOM Ready.
Basically, I have pages that load the following (on a search query):

www.myawesomesiteimadetoday.com/dir/keyword/test

The page may also load a URL based on a selection of search filters, such as followers:

www.myawesomesiteimadetoday.com/dir/companies/keyword/test/type/d
OR EVEN
www.myawesomesiteimadetoday.com/dir/companies/type/d/keyword/test/

My goal:
To basically find/get the value of the string immediately after '/keyword/'

I've been able to use JS to get the 'value of the last component of string' - but this does not work because as shown above, the URL may 'change' and the value will not always be the 'last component'

```
function(){
   var cu = {{Page URL}};
   var l = cu.split("/").length;
   return cu.split("/")[l-1];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function getParam(urlStr) {
  if (/\/keyword\//g.test(urlStr)) {
    var arr = urlStr.split("/")
    var index = arr.indexOf("keyword") + 1
    return arr[index]
  } else {
    return "not found"
  }
}
```

You can use a RegExp to judge whether '/keyword/' exists or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can split with the `/keyword/` string and get the right side of the result.

`cu.split("/keyword/")[1]`

Comment: This only works if the keyword is the second to last component.

Comment: i understood that he wants the whole chunk after the `/keyword/` part

Answer (score 0):

Split the url on '/' then get the index of 'keyword' +1 from the array.

```
var parts = cu.split("/");
return parts[parts.indexOf("keyword") + 1];
```

This would fail if 'keyword' was not in the url so you may want to check for that.

```
var parts = cu.split("/");
return parts[(parts.indexOf("keyword") > -1 ? parts.indexOf("keyword") + 1 : "not found")];
```